use name type as text type in flow
I am trying to use the Name field under user as the value for another item in a salesforce flow. however it seems to be failing because the User Name field is Name type, while the destination field is text type.
can I make this work somehow?

Not an answer, but will your use conform with GDPR or other legislation (since Name for a user is PII)?

Have you tried using a formula that converts the name to text via TEXT()?

Does TEXT($Record.Name) work?

The answer and your comment makes me think the question is poorly phrased. I assumed you were talking about the User Object.

@PhilW I am talking about User object, as mentioned in the question

I have worked with Person Account Objects where the Name field is a compound field and consists of the FirstName, LastName etc.
If I wanted to use the Name field as either a merge field in a message, or some other way, then I would just opt for:
{!$Record.FirstName}+" "+{!$Record.LastName}

Good luck!

I think this worked - but I just needed to do {!$Record.FirstName} {!$Record.LastName}

That suggests this is not the User object's Name field, but instead Contact Object Name.

@PhilW its definitely the User object - it seems you are confused

OK, I certainly did get confused! ;)

@user149493 if my answer got it sorted, I would really appreciate it if you marked my answer as the solution. Thanks!
